# Boot partition size problem

Tags: 14.04

I have created an ISO of ubuntu 14.04 after installing some packages by using remastersys. I tested that ISO, it was working fine. But after one month when I tried the same iso it start prompting me the following error. When I use LVM method for partition, it prompt the below error.

some of the partition you created are too small. Please make please make the following partition at least this larg   /boot 264.8 MB
[image]

When I use something else (customize partition method) it prompt the following error just before installation complete as shown in picture. i am using 200 GM Disk.
[image]